# Getting authentication of actual user to not ask for authentication again

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, cookies

So I have made an authentication of the user in angularjs. I am working with MongoDB on deployed. I can store the user in cookies but I am trying to store the authentication in cookies because every time I try to get to user panel it ask me for the username and password but the user is already stored in cookies. When I get the user from cookies it's still ask me to log in again.

part of my `adminController.js` with part of authentication :

```
.controller("authCtrl", function($scope, $http, $location, authUrl) {
$scope.authenticate = function (login, pass) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:5500/users/me')
    $http.post(authUrl, {
        username: login,
        password: pass
    }, {
        withCredentials: true
    }).success(function (data) {

        $location.path("/main");
    }).error(function (error) {
        $scope.authenticationError = error;
    });
};
})
```

my `cuurentUserController.js`:

```
angular.module("sportsStoreAdmin")
    .config(function($httpProvider){
        $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    })
.controller("currentCtrl" ,function ($http, $scope, $cookieStore) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:5500/users/me')
        .success(function (user) {
            $scope.user = user;
            $cookieStore.put('user', user);
        });
});
```

cookies after i log in :

```
%7B%22username%22%3A%22user%22%2C%22id%22%3A%228616b29237ade8b0%22%7D
```

So as you can see the logged in user is stored in cookies but still it ask me to log in again and again.

I know that this part of `adminController.js` in not enought because it only gets the actual user but doesn't put him in authentication:

```
$cookieStore.get('user')
```

What should i do to get this working ?

**EDIT:**
So i was trying more things and found in `deployed` docs that i could get the actual user in authentication with in place of `$cookieStore.get('user')` by using this :

```
$http.get('http://localhost:5500/users/me')
```

So i have edited part of my `adminController.js`and it looks now like above.

But is still doesn't first check if user is already authenticated and ask to authenticate. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time i have learnd much of AgnularJS and the anwser was simple as that, creat an scope for example `$scope.authenticated = 0` on succesCallback while login in set it to `$scope.authenticated = 1` and store it in cookies.